# CSS and JS Transitions with GSAP

Tags: javascript, gsap, anime.js

https://codepen.io/thatfemicode/pen/MWpwaRQ

https://twitter.com/P_h_l_i_x/status/1353659923834544128

Evening, after much though and hands on, i came up with a solution, but still not okay with what i have, i am trying to make this exact thing as shown in the influencers section in the TWITTER link of the page below See how each loop changes class to the class of the previous element before leaving the viewport, how can i achieve that? thanks, any advice will be much appreciated

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="fakeImages" id="fake1"></div>
      <div class="fakeImages" id="fake2"></div>
      <div class="fakeImages" id="fake3"></div>
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
        alt="view"
        id="img1"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY="
        alt="powder"
        id="img2"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG"
        alt="powder"
        id="img3"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_before_mobile.jpg"
        alt="bird"
        id="img4"
        class="images"
      />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  .images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #img4 {
    z-index: -5;
  }
  .fakeImages {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -9;
  }
  #fake1 {
    background: lightgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(20deg);
  }
  #fake2 {
    background: grey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  #fake3 {
    background: darkgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-15deg);
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
 function play() {
      let images = gsap.utils.toArray('.images');
      let fakes = gsap.utils.toArray('.fakeImages');
      let tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1 });
      let tl2 = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 0 });
      tl.set(images, {
        zIndex: (i) => i * -1,
        rotation: (i) => Math.random() * 30 - 15,
      });
      tl.to(images, {
        duration: 1,
        rotation: 0,
        delay: (i) => i * 1 + 1,
        x: 2000,
        // scale: 0,
        // css: { className: '+=active' },
      });
    }
    play();
```

Comment: Check out [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) GSAP plugin. you can create any what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this can be found on the codepen.io after an improvement was made on the code by someone from GSAP and I also added my modifications.

https://codepen.io/thatfemicode/pen/OJpNXEr

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<!--       <div class="fakeImages" id="fake1"></div>
      <div class="fakeImages" id="fake2"></div>
      <div class="fakeImages" id="fake3"></div> -->
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
        alt="view"
        id="img1"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY="
        alt="powder"
        id="img2"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG"
        alt="powder"
        id="img3"
        class="images"
      />
      <img
        src="https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_before_mobile.jpg"
        alt="bird"
        id="img4"
        class="images"
      />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  .images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #img4 {
    z-index: -5;
  }
  .fakeImages {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -9;
  }
  #fake1 {
    background: lightgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(20deg);
  }
  #fake2 {
    background: grey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  #fake3 {
    background: darkgrey;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-15deg);
  }
}
```

Javsscript using GSAP

```
function play() {
  let images = gsap.utils.toArray('.images');
  let fakes = gsap.utils.toArray('.fakeImages');
  let all = images.concat(fakes);
  let tl = gsap.timeline({ delay: 1, repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1 });
  gsap.set(images, {
    zIndex: (i) => i * -1,
    // rotation: "random(-15,15)",
  });
  // make sure the "top" image is exactly 8 degrees
  gsap.set(images[0], {rotation: 8});
  gsap.set(images[1], {rotation: -8})
  gsap.set(images[2], {rotation: 8})
  gsap.set(images[3], {rotation: -8})
  // at the start, remove all "active" classes
  tl.call(() => images.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active")));
  tl.to(images, {
    x: 2000,
    duration: 1,
    ease: "power2.in",
    stagger: {
      each: 1.5,
      onStart() {
        let leavingEl = this.targets()[0],
            enteringEl = all[all.indexOf(leavingEl) + 1];
        // console.log(leavingEl)
        console.log(this.targets())
        //leavingEl.classList.add("active"); // if you want to set a class on the one animating out, you could do it like this.       
        gsap.to(all, {
          ease: "power2.inOut",
          duration: 0.6,
          // rotation: 0
          // function-based value - if it's the entering element, make it exactly 8 degrees. Otherwise, randomize it between -15 and 15 degrees.
          // rotation: (i, target) => target === enteringEl ? 8 : gsap.utils.random(-15, 15)
           rotation: (i, target) => target === enteringEl ? 8 : gsap.utils.random([4, -4,])
        // });
        })
      }
    }
  });
}
play();
```